# Since I migrated vCenter to 5.1, some vms are migrating again and again

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-esx, vmware-vcenter, vmotion

Yesterday I upgraded my vCenter to the last version 5.1 and I had to reconnect the hosts (running esx 5.0, last patches)

Since I migrated, 5 vms (always the same) are vMotionned from host to host and when it's done it vMotions again to another host... (I can see in the task that DRS launched this operation) and then vMotion again and again

My hosts have enough free memory and enough free CPU on every hosts...

Should I be worried?

Thank you

Philippe

Comment: What level of DRS automation is set.

Comment: Fully automated and the cursor is set to "Aggressive"

Comment: I've only got 5.1 in labs and use the next level up from aggressive (the second one, can't recall the name) but haven't seen that behaviour, maybe they changed the thresholds with 5.1 to be super-aggressive? either way you have the option to move it from aggressive to a lower level, I'd try that first.

Comment: So I set the Migration threshold's cursor to the minimum (Conservative)... There are two clusters in my farm, only on of them is having this issue. Weird

Comment: I'd put a case in with VMW to be honest, they'e very good I find.

Comment: So they stopped moving at minimum level.
I asked the same question in VMWare's forum. Thank you for your help

Comment: No problem, I'm not going into production with 5.1 until November (work for a very change-averse company), please let us all know if you have an issues if you would.